# Defining a IP whitelist for calls from Azure Datacenters Easily

Tags: azure

I am looking for an easy way I can give to clients for whitelisting IP addresses from Azure Data Centers.  Previously I sent a list from Microsoft on all IP addresses the datacenter may use.  Can I use something like a subnet or a similar technique?

I have a series of Azure functions that make calls to websites.  Some websites are using an IP Whitelist and managing all the possible Azure IP addresses that calls can be made from is cumbersome.  I send links to the clients for the Latest list of IP addresses from Microsoft.

Comment: You mention Functions, how about using NAT Gateway then to make your outbound calls? https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/11/15/web-app-nat-gateway.html

Comment: Ths could be an option in the future.  We will have to evaluate and test.  I have a few clients currently that need solutions now.  Also I usually wait a few months on any new service.

Comment: Well then how about this? It requires, however, that your Function runs on an App Service plan, not consumption plan https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses#find-outbound-ip-addresses